# array_merge issue in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have some problems during working with arrays using the `array_merge` function. Here's an example:

```php
$first_array = [
    8 => [
        'name' => "Hershey's Chocolate Milk Shake",
        'code' => 8 ,
        'price' => 29.00,
        'quantity' => 1,
        'image' => "Hersheys_Chocolate_Milk_Shake.jpg",
        'percentage_discount' => 0,
        'offer_mrp' => 0,
    ]
];
$second_array = [
    20 => [
        'name' => 'Kissan Mixed Fruit Jam 700g',
        'code' => 20,
        'price' => 215.00,
        'quantity' => 1,
        'image' => 'Kissan Mixed Fruit Jam 700g.jpg',
        'percentage_discount' => 0,
        'offer_mrp' => 0 
    ]
];

$first_array = array_merge($first_array, $second_array); 
print_r($first_array);
```

The result is:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [name] => Hershey's Chocolate Milk Shake 
        [code] => 8 
        [price] => 29.00 
        [quantity] => 1 
        [image] => Hersheys_Chocolate_Milk_Shake.jpg 
        [percentage_discount] => 0 
        [offer_mrp] => 0
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [name] => Kissan Mixed Fruit Jam 700g 
        [code] => 20 
        [price] => 215.00 
        [quantity] => 1 
        [image] => Kissan Mixed Fruit Jam 700g.jpg 
        [percentage_discount] => 0 [offer_mrp] => 0 
    ) 
);
```

But I want it to be:

```
Array ( 
    [8] => Array ( 
        [name] => Hershey's Chocolate Milk Shake 
        [code] => 8 
        [price] => 29.00 
        [quantity] => 1 
        [image] => Hersheys_Chocolate_Milk_Shake.jpg 
        [percentage_discount] => 0 
        [offer_mrp] => 0
    ) 
    [20] => Array ( 
        [name] => Kissan Mixed Fruit Jam 700g 
        [code] => 20 
        [price] => 215.00 
        [quantity] => 1 
        [image] => Kissan Mixed Fruit Jam 700g.jpg 
        [percentage_discount] => 0 [offer_mrp] => 0 
    )
)
```

Comment: Just use simple `+`, it doesn't overwrite keys.

Comment: Can you please use formatting? and if possible please echo/print your variables like this, because it's unreadable:
echo '<pre>' . print_r($first_array, true) . '</pre>';

Comment: @u_mulder array_merge() do not over-write keys..

Comment: Thanks for your solution and it is done using + operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_merge()` renumerates numeric keys. You should use operator `+` instead.

```
$first_array = $first_array + $second_array;
```

Output is exactly the same as you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for solution and it is run successfully.

Comment: @Manish Please mark answer as correct if it resolved your question.